# How can I pass variable of "phoneNumberState.value" from ScreenA to ScreenB in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have one variable in screen A as  val `phoneNumberState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }` and I want to pass this argument to screen B, so I try to do it on internet, there is some example, I confused how to apply, is there  easy way for it?

**navigation:**

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun Navigation(
startDestination: String
) {

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {


    composable("screenA" ) {
        ScreenA(navController = navController)
    }




    composable("screenB") {
        ScreenB(navController = navController)

    }}}
```

**ScreenA:**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA(

    navController: NavController,
   

    ) {
 val phoneNumberState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }


        OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumberState.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = color,
                textColor = color,

                ),
            onValueChange = { phoneNumberState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            singleLine = true,
        
   
        )
      Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(285.dp)
                    .height(55.dp)

                ,
                onClick = {
                    
                  
             
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = color
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(40),
               

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "send",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        color = white,


                        )

                )
            }
```

**ScreenB:**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB(
    navController: NavController,
 
   
) {
    lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val phoneNumberPatientOTP = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("found activity? ${context.findActivity()}")
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        modelAuthentication.setActivity(activity)
    }


    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

            OutlinedTextField(
                value = phoneNumberOTP.value,
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = white,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    cursorColor = color,
                    textColor = color,

                    ),
                onValueChange = { phoneNumberOTP.value = it },
                label = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),

                )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(7.dp))

        Row(
            Modifier
                .width(300.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,

            ) {

            Text(
                "Resend Code",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        
                       


                    }
                ,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = color
            )
        } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Navigation compose document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation):

first change your ScreenB's constructor to this:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB(
    navController: NavController,
    number: String
) {...}
```

then change your NavHost setup like below:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {


    composable("screenA" ) {
        ScreenA(navController = navController)
    }

    composable("screenB/{number}") { backStackEntry ->
        ScreenB(navController = navController , backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("number"))

    }}}
```

then in your button onclick in **ScreenA** call navigate with your state value

```
onClick = {
    navController.navigate("screenB/${phoneNumberState.value}")
}
```

now you have access to your **number** in ScreenB's constructor :)

**UPDATE**

if you want to pass it to another Composable from ScreenB then first you should create your new Screen

```
@Composable
fun ScreenC(
    navController: NavController,
    number: String
) {...}
```

then add the new destination to your NavHost:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {


    composable("screenA" ) {
        ScreenA(navController = navController)
    }

    composable("screenB/{number}") { backStackEntry ->
        ScreenB(navController = navController , backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("number"))

    composable("screenC/{number}") { backStackEntry ->
        ScreenC(navController = navController , backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("number"))
    }}}
```

**number** in your ScreenB is now a variable of type string. its not state anymore,
so if you want to use it in **ScreenB** just call a simple navigate fun and use your number variable:

```
onClick = {
    navController.navigate("screenC/$number")
}
```

Comment: tnx so much, but how can I use it in screen B, if I want to pass from B to C screen, I will again say ` navController.navigate("screenC/${phoneNumberState.value}")` ? I am not get it,

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your question. in summary to add an argument to a destination first you should define it in your NavHost setup and then add your arguments to Screen's constructor

Comment: how can I use phoneNumberState.value in screen B, what is it number here, I will use number in screen B instead of the phoneNumberState.value?

Comment: @Huma33 you can name the variable what ever you want. number is just an example here. we added this in NavHost :composable("screenB/{number}") . you can replace the {number} with what ever name you like.({phoneNumber} or {userNumber} or ...) its just a name so that you can use it in your screenB.

Comment: Navigation in compose is like working with web urls. what ever you put after / will be just a Tag. we used number so that we can get the argument in navHost. number is only a TAG we use to get backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("number").

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add argument placeholders to your route.

```
composable("screenB/{phoneNumber}")
```

and you can append your value like this, I assume you want to do it inside Button's onClick lambda

```
onClick = {
  navController.navigate("screenB/${phoneNumberState.value}")
}
```

then retrieve it like this, inside your NavHost

```
NavHost(...){
composable("screenB/{phoneNumber}") { backStackEntry ->
ScreenB(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("phoneNumber"))
}
}
```

Comment: tnx for ur answer, where is screenA here? `composable("screenB/{phoneNumber}")` this is for B or A